# BOM at PHP file won't get handled with zend.multibyte

Tags: php, utf-8

My favorite PHP editor Codelobster is always adding a UTF-8 BOM at my PHP files.

So this BOM is sent to the clients. While it works fine with most browsers, Google Chrome has a problem with it: According to the inspector, it adds `&#65279;` into the `<body>` of the HTML, resulting in an ugly padding above the follow-up `<form>` .

[image]

I want to solve this problem by stripping the UTF-8 from the HTTP-Output.

I have read that setting `zend.multibyte = On` in the PHP.ini will handle the UTF-8 BOM of the PHP files, and therefore avoid passing them to the client.

But it doesn't work. What should I do?

**reproduction.php** (in ASCII representation)

```
ï»¿<?php

// Just a demonstration to show that the UTF-8 BOM was actually sent
flush();
header('abc:def'); // will fail, because of the previously sent BOM

// Now check that the change in the PHP file did work.
var_dump(ini_get('zend.multibyte')); // string(1) "1"

?>
```

Additional information about the environment:

- PHP 5.6.8
- SAPI: Apache 2.0 Handler
- Apache 2.4.10
- Windows server

Comment: Ultimately you should get your editor to save the files as you require instead of requiring elaborate workarounds.

Comment: @deceze I personally don't see BOMs as a bad thing. Without UTF-8, I couldn't comment the code in different languages than English.

Comment: Surely there's a setting to save the file as UTF-8 without BOM? You can do it in Notepad++ ... You've already found BOM *is* a bad thing with that `header(...)` call

Comment: You can use UTF-8 perfectly fine without a BOM. A BOM is entirely optional and mostly non-functional for UTF-8.